# String analyzer

Tags: python

Whats the shortest way to code this in Python? can i include counter inside a loop that can check and count the inputted strings?

```
from collections import Counter
    
    ans = 'y'
    while ans == 'y' or ans == 'Y':
        print 'String Analyzer ver 1.0'
     
        string = raw_input('Enter a String: ')
    
        counter = Counter(string)
    
        counter['a'],counter['A'],counter['b'],counter['B'],counter['c'],counter['C'],counter['d'],counter['D'],counter['e'],counter['E'],counter['f'],counter['F']
        counter['g'],counter['G'],counter['h'],counter['H'],counter['i'],counter['I'],counter['j'],counter['J'],counter['k'],counter['K'],counter['l'],counter['L']
        counter['m'],counter['M'],counter['n'],counter['N'],counter['o'],counter['O'],counter['p'],counter['P'],counter['q'],counter['Q'],counter['r'],counter['R']
        counter['s'],counter['S'],counter['t'],counter['T'],counter['u'],counter['U'],counter['v'],counter['V'],counter['w'],counter['W'],counter['x'],counter['X']
        counter['y'],counter['Y'],counter['z'],counter['Z']
        letterU = counter['A'] + counter['B'] + counter['C'] + counter['D'] + counter['E'] + counter['F'] + counter['G'] + counter['H'] + counter['I'] + counter['J']+ counter['K'] + counter['L'] + counter['M'] + counter['N'] + counter['O'] + counter['P'] + counter['Q'] + counter['R'] + counter['S'] + counter['T'] + counter['U']+ counter['V'] + counter['W'] + counter['X'] + counter['Y'] + counter['Z']
        letterL = counter['a'] + counter['b'] + counter['c'] + counter['d'] + counter['e'] + counter['f'] + counter['g'] + counter['h'] + counter['i'] + counter['j']+ counter['k'] + counter['l'] + counter['m'] + counter['n'] + counter['o'] + counter['p'] + counter['q'] + counter['r'] + counter['s'] + counter['t'] + counter['u']+ counter['v'] + counter['w'] + counter['x'] + counter['y'] + counter['z']
        LET = letterU + letterL
    
        counter['0'],counter['1'],counter['2'],counter['3'],counter['4'],counter['5'],counter['6'],counter['7'],counter['8'],counter['9']
        NUM = counter['0'] + counter['1'] + counter['2'] + counter['3'] + counter['4'] + counter['5'] + counter['6'] + counter['7'] + counter['8'] + counter['9']
    
        counter['\n'],counter['/t'],counter[' '],counter[':'],counter["'"],counter['"'],counter['<'],counter['>'],counter['='],counter['+'],counter['-'],counter['*'],counter['/']
        OTH = counter['\n'] + counter['/t'] + counter[' '] + counter[':'] + counter["'"] + counter['"'] + counter['<'] + counter['>'] + counter['='] + counter['+'] + counter['-'] + counter['*'] + counter['/']
    
        print 'Result Analysis \n'
        print 'Length of the String: ', len(string)
        print 'no. of Letters: ', LET
        print 'no. of Numbers: ', NUM
        print 'no. of Other Characters: ', OTH
    
        ans = raw_input('Try Again? [Y/N] ')
```

Comment: Why don't you show us how far you've gotten so far, and pinpoint where you're getting hung up? It will be easier for us to give you a more targeted response,and you'll probably get more replies.

Comment: im trying to sort out  all the inputted character. and i dont know how to start. ive only come with this code that tells the lenght of the inputted string  inp = input ("Enter a String: ")
print ("No. of Strings: {}".format(len(inp)))

Comment: You should tell us what exactly it is that you want to do and what the problem with your code is. For me it is not clear what you want to do with these counter objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
number = 0
alphabet = 0
special = 0
for i in string:
    if i.isnumeric():
        number +=1
    if i.isalpha():
        alphabet +=1
    if i.isascii():
        special +=1
print('no. of Number: ',number)
print('no. of letters: ',alphabet)
print('no. of Other Characters: ',special - (number+alphabet))`
```